# Is CAPTCHA necessary when I use an anti-CSRF token?

Tags: authentication, captcha, token

I wonder is it a good idea using captcha when using an anti-CSRF token on login page? I think it's impossible for robots to mess with login page because the token changes on every request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my idea captcha in login page is unnecessary and just bothering users you can use captcha after several attempts you can avoid attacker by using token and as I said captcha after several failing attempt.
Use captcha in sign up page and use token in every form that you have in your web site.

Comment: Your answer is inappropriate. I AM using captcha in sign-up page. __In my idea captcha in login page is unnecessary__ WHY it's unnecessary?!

Comment: I said "bothering users" but it seems you have already know your answer before asking it and just want someone to say your idea.

Answer (score 7):

Yes its neccessary. A token can still be requested by a bruteforcer. Yes, it would cost the bruteforcer one request extra per try, but a captcha still blocks attempts completely instead.

If you dont want to bother your users with a captcha, you could set so when a incorrect password is used, the account in question will require a captcha. This both thwarth bruteforcers, but also alert the original account holder, that someone might try to access his account. To avoid that a bot might figure which accounts that exist or not, store this flag also for non-existing accounts.

Answer (score 2):

CSRF tokens aren't intended as a protection against bots at all. They're only intended as a protection against CSRF attacks. It's only coincidental that some bots don't handle CSRF tokens correctly, but many do. If you're worried about bots, then you should still use a CAPTCHA; the presence of CSRF tokens should not influence your decision on that.